# Separating Android Lists with Headers

Tags: android, list, listview, header, separator

Alright I've been searching for the past couple days. I keep finding the custom classes that people have made to achieve this. Particularly [Jeff Sharkey's class](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) and the Commonsware class.

I noticed Jeff Sharkey published that in 2008. Now that was a while ago. Has google integrated a way of doing this without having to use custom classes? I'd really like to not have to use a custom class and just stick with the java/android sdks

Answer (score 1):

I have a twolinelistview.xml in which I have 2 text views.  I populate the bottomtext with the regular data and the toptext with header data.  The empty header items don't cause me any issues.

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView toptext;
    TextView bottomtext;
}
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lv_topText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@drawable/ltGrey" 
        android:background="@drawable/semiTransparentDrk"
        android:textSize="24sp" 
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:padding="10sp"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lv_bottomText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@drawable/ltGrey" 
        android:background="@drawable/semiTransparentDrk"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think ill stick with jeff sharkey's class then. I found it easier to implement than this. Thanks for the response though

Comment: I didn't look at his example until your comment.  You can't beat a fully working code example ;)  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

No. Google supplies an SDK with basic components with enough extensibility to allow developers to leverage the existing to work to create their own components, without having to do most of the hard stuff.

Something like list headers is not all that hard either, their is really no need for Google to add it to the SDK.

If what you want to do is avoid re-making components every time you use a project, then set up your favorite classes in an Android Library Project. There are also libraries with components with extra functionality such as [Green Droid](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=240) and others.

Comment: List headers are probably not hard for someone who has been doing java for a while, but for someone who has only been doing it for a week it was quite difficult. Luckily I have a lot of actionscript, javascript and php in my background so it hasn't been too much of a hurdle getting over. I'm still trying to find my way around eclipse :D. I get what your saying though. I'll check out green droid.